# trouble pairing bluetooth headphones 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

Has anyone figured out a fix for the bluetooth? I am having trouble connecting skull candy crushers to my laptop(16.04). It seems like the only way possible is to always unpair in settings-> bluetooth, then put them into discovery mode, then go into sound and change output to the headphone name, then go into blueman and change the audio profile, and this still doesn't usually even work for me. Any fixes or could anyone help me out? Thanks!

[edit] here is the output:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21ce]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 062a:4101 Creative Labs Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b217 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Lenovo Integrated Camera (0.3MP)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: It look like this device `0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)` is not well supported on Linux.

Comment: so what do I do about my headphones?

Answer (score 0):

See the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1577197) and use the a2dp.py file to switch it to the high quality A2DP audio.

A possible alternative using Blueman is to switch the headphones to the off profile, then disconnect, reconnect and switch to the A2DP profile